# Rails / Haml: How to create a post form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I'm trying to make a simple form, but it's working not so fine.
This is my current form code:

```
%form{ :controller => 'tool', :action => 'activation', :method => 'post' }
  %table{ :border => 0, :width => "100%", :height => "100%" }
    %tr{ :align => "center", :valign => "center" }
      %td
        %input{ :type => "text", :name => "accountName" }
        %input{ :type => "submit", :name => "submit", :value => "login" }
```

I am getting this url when trying to send data via form: `10.0.0.2:3000/activation`.
I know that I can make route `tool#activation` to activation, but it's a wrong way, I want to sent post query to `10.0.0.2:3000/tool/activation`, but `:action => 'tool/activation'` also is a bad way as far as I understand.

Can you give me advice ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the rails helper tags.

```
= form_tag tool_activation_path, :method => :post do
    # The table
        # The row
            # The data
                = text_field_tag "accountName", ""
                = submit_tag "Submit"
```

See more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

Also, you should try to avoid unnecessary tables to style your layout. Instead, look to using CSS.

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to accept the answer so any one else with a similar problem will know what worked for you.